# How do I load Excel files selectively?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that needs to lookup two different types of excel files, type A and type B and load the data within to two different staging tables, tableA and tableB. The formats of these excel sheets are different and they match their respective tables.

I have thought of putting typeA.xls and typeB.xls in two different folders for simplicity(folder paths to be configureable). The required excel files will then be put here through some other application or manually.

What I want is to be able to have my dtsx package to scan the folder and pick the latest unprocessed file and load it ignoring others and then postfix the file name with '-loaded' (typeAxxxxxx-loaded.xls). The "-loaded" in the filename is how I plan to differentiate between the already loaded files and the ones yet to be loaded.

I need advice on:

a) How to check that configured folder for the latest file ie. without the '-loaded' in the filename and load it? ..and then after loading it, rename the same file in that configured folder with the '-loaded' postfixed.

b) Is this the best approach to doing this or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, but it might require several complex string expressions.

E.g. create a ForEach loop over .xls files, inside the loop add an empty script task, then a data flow to load this file. Connect them with a precedence constraint and make it conditional: precedence constraint expression will the check if file name does not end with -loaded.xls. You may either do it in script task or purely using SSIS expression on precedence constraint. Finally, add File System Task to rename the file. You may need to build new file name with another expression.

It might be easier to create two folders: Incoming for new unprocessed files, and Loaded for the files you've processed, and just move the .xls to this folder after processing without renaming. This will avoid the first conditional expression (and dummy script task), and simplify the configuration of File System task.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the SQL File watcher Task and add it to your SSIS.  I think this is a cleaner way to do what you want.

[SQL File Watcher](http://www.sqlis.com/post/File-Watcher-Task.aspx)